# Combining Quantitative data with fundamental data

Tags: programming, quantitative, machine-learning, fundamentals

These day, there is relatively new phenomena of combining quantitative data and fundamental data called '**Quantamentals'**.

In this regards, I was wondering how to combine Four Essential Types of Financial Data

**1) Fundamental Data(eg. Asset, Liability,sales)

2) Market Data(Volume, Price/Yield,Volatility)

3) Analytics Data(Analyst Recommendations, Credit Rating) and**
**4) Alternative Date(Satellite, Twitter)**

into ***one data frame*** for analyses, given difference in frequency.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two ways of doing it:

1) Resampling them to their median frequency.
2) Build one ML model for each data type, then combine the 4 different forecasts into a single meta-ML model.

(Courtesy: MARCOS LO´PEZ DE PRADO)

Answer (score 0):

Consider investigating the MIDAS approach of incorporating signals with different frequencies.

The classical apporach is to create a signal based on each source and tune it to your trading/rebalancing frequency. Convert this signal to an alpha based on Grinold and Khan, then add the alphas together.

Comment: Are there any machine learning models for MIDAS or kalman-filters

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that if we turn to Arbitrage Pricing Theory then we can model the returns of the asset by some linear combination of the features.

Take the [Carhart four-factor model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carhart_four-factor_model) as an example it incorporates financial statement features with momentum which is a feature derived from closing prices.

There are two books that provide a lot of context: [Quantitative Equity Portfolio Management](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071459391) & the bible of factor investing [Active Portfolio Management](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0070248826).

Another common technique is to make use of a dimensionality reduction algorithm such as PCA to decompose all your different features into a few features that are information rich.